# Detecting lamp failure in electronic ballasts

Tags: electronic-ballast

What would be a simple solution for detecting lamp failure in fluorescent tube ECG's?

There are 3 control gears running 6 (40w/4pin) lamps that need to have detection of lamp failure. While ECG's have a simple way to detect failure on the control circuit how would you go around the issue to detect lamp failure with available high frequency outputs?

Current measurement on input side seemed like a decent idea, but the L-N polarity may be reversed - as such that becomes problematic (the inrush current is another issue ~31A / ecg). I can only think of using the lamp output HF side, but am unsure of how to approach the matter in a reliable way with minimal work and off the shelf components.

There are ballasts available with contacts for lamp failure but they tend to be around 80$ as opposed to 15$ for regular ones.

Comment: Try an optical sensor on the lamp itself?

Comment: Easiest way to measure lamp failure is to measure current. But that requires everything being stable enough you can clearly detect the difference in current if the lamp is working or not.

Comment: @rdtsc Optical sensor is not an option as shadows may be cast and it is necessary to make sure that all lamps are on.

Comment: @Puffafish that was my first intuition as well as just not sure what would be the simplest solution for it

Answer (score 2):

The change in characteristics of aging fluorescent lamps has been pretty well studied, at least for linear tubular lamps. There are end-of-life characteristics known (but not by me) and observed in what used to be modern electronic ballasts.

T12 and T8 lamps didn't behave too badly toward the end, as far as resigning quietly goes, but T5, at least in their early days, changed drastically enough to require more assertive EOL circuitry. I read about this in the early 90's but don't remember whether there were electrical stresses on the ballast circuitry or just other things like crest factor and THD/EMI/EMC issues going back into the AC line/mains.

Lamp failure for fluorescent lamps is basically defined as a failure to ignite, and the number of hours being the average for half a group of lamps. So 'industry' leaned toward replacing large numbers of lamps on a schedule so they reduce repeated labor as lamps start failing in succession somewhere on the bell curve. There are other benefits to replacing them before they fail. We've all seen places where there is NO lamp maintenance until the situation is pathetic.

I am looking at a lamp failure detector right now in an 80's UVC PROM eraser with 8 UV-C fluorescent lamps, 8 starters and 4 magnetic ballasts for series lamps. There is a pair of back-to-back pair of diodes for each ballast, with one common lead and a neon lamp to indicate failure. One diode in each pair was a 1N400? (installed upside down so I couldn't read last digit)and the second was an orange glass diode with markings I never deciphered or couldn't see fully. My hunch was one was a Zener, and any ballast that has a pair of lamps that don't light would have higher voltage than the plasma/arc/column voltage and cause the common 'lamp fail' neon lamp to light. (The rectifier would produce a half-wave rectified, unfiltered (rippled) DC level and the Zener would conduct where a lamp pair didn't light). The ballast would limit the current on the AC side feeding the diode circuit.

Except I just replaced the lamps & ballasts & they all light now...but the Lamp Fail indicator still illuminates. That's how I got here today...hoping I could trade some lamp trivia with someone (who probably would have to be older than me).

I just realized this is about 3 years old. Maybe the original poster  uses LED's now ;O)

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the detailed reply!

We ended up solving the issue by checking the voltage after ignition period (delay on power up ~2 sec, running throughout the 'on' sequence). The ballasts fail to start if the voltage check circuit is connected on system power up, thus a simple time delay relay solved the issue. Ballasts performed normally after initial power up without extra circuits connected. 

The aperture in question was UV disinfecting cabinet. The fluorescent lamps were outperforming the LEDs at the time, especially considering failure modes and price points per watt.